# Como adaptar um Activity para FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment, streaming

Estou fazendo um `NavigationDrawer`, e daí tenho que fazer algumas adaptações, pois estou estendendo `Fragment`, mas preciso usar int's para Activity funcionar, tentei chamar dentro de `OnCreateView` o `FragmentActivity` mas não deu muito certo.

É esta classe aqui:

```
package player.kmk.com.kmk;


import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Z0NEN on 10/22/2014.
 */
public class menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;
    private boolean isPlaying;
    private ImageButton playButton;
    private String urlStreaming;
    private menu1_Fragment station;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
     //   listen.ouvir();
    //    listen.definirVolumeSlider();
         Bundle bundle;

        playButton = ((ImageButton).findViewById(R.id.play_button));
        this.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
            {
                if (isPlaying)
                {
                    audioStreamer.interrupt();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
                if (!isPlaying)
                {
                    startStreamingAudio();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
                isPlaying=!isPlaying;
            }
        });
        this.audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
        int i = this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
        int j = this.audioManager.getStreamVolume(3);
        setVolumeControlStream(3);
        SeekBar localSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        localSeekBar.setMax(i);
        localSeekBar.setProgress(j);
        localSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar, int paramAnonymousInt, boolean paramAnonymousBoolean)
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(3, paramAnonymousInt, 0);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
            {
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
            {
            }
        });
        return rootview;


    }



    public void startStreamingAudio()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.audioStreamer != null)
                this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
            this.audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, playButton);
            this.audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://sh.upx.com.br:10369", 5208L, 216L);
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException localIOException)
        {
            while (true)
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", localIOException);
        }
    }



    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (this.audioStreamer != null)
            this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Do modo que está é insustentável, pois está como Fragment, como faço adaptações com Activity de determinadas funções como setar o player para tocar com o findByViewId ou controlar o volume com o Seek Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar findViewById no método onCreateView() do fragmento assim:

```
rootView.findViewById(id);
```

Dentro do fragmento mas fora de onCreateView() faça assim:

```
getView().findViewById(id);
```

Para as demais situações em que uma Activity ou Context é requerida usar o getActivity().

Comment: Vou tentar e no caso do getSistemService()?

Comment: Faça getActivity().getSystemService();

Comment: Pode mostrar um exemplo com o getView()?

Comment: Consegui:        playButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.play_button);
no primeiro caso.

Comment: Não consegui neste situação:        this.audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
.

Comment: Bom, a resposta foi aceita então estou imaginando que conseguiu. De qualquer forma, seria this.audioManager = (AudioManager)(getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));

Comment: Obrigado. No .setVolumeControlStream(3) eu coloquei um getActivity() para pegar a atividade e não marcou erro, está certo?

Comment: Está certo sim.

Comment: E nestes casos que aparece o erro "Cannot resolve method ´get intent`" o que eu faço utilizando ainda o Activity no Fragment:
       feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");
        int pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");

Comment: Também, getActivity().getIntent().get...

Comment: Tinha tentado antes de perguntar e tentei novamente mas aparece o erro aonde invoca

Comment: Aí já não sei dizer o que pode estar acontecendo. Pelo erro que você citou parece que getIntent() está escrito errado: "get intent". Crie uma nova pergunta e forneça mais detalhes.

Comment: Não está com erro ortográfico, agora é de rodar. Veja aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109202/erro-de-chamada.